# Getting different result using Mysql UNIX_TIMESTAMP() to JAVASCRIPT Date.UTC()

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, angularjs, datetime

I need to supply the values of Javascript `Date.UTC()` to an array of graph. When I am doing it manually like `Date.UTC(2016, 2, 21)` 
which is equivalent to  '`2016-03-21`' then it's working fine but I need to fetch the results from `Mysql` not manually so I am using `UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2016-03-21') * 1000` but the strange thing is I am getting different result for both. How to make same ?

```
Date.UTC(2016, 2, 21) = 1458518400000
UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2016-03-21') * 1000 = 1458498600000
```

Comment: Yes, In Date.UTC() the Jan = 0 and so on, you can try it in console.

Comment: I have tried to change Timezone of MYSQL still not working.

Comment: UTC time has TZ time difference.... difference here is `+5:30` which is `IST`

Comment: So, what you suggest, how to make both results equal ?

Comment: I have tried to set MYSQL time zone with set time_zone = '-5:00'; still not working

Answer (score 1):

The problem was I needed to covert the timezone first to match the results by  using following statement

```
set time_zone = 'value'
```